# Tanto- to mean so much so

Tags: gramática, frase

I know tanto and tan and its other forms can be used to compare things/people and as an adverb. I also know about "tanto como" to mean as much as. I understand those rules.

My question is :does tanto change to tanta when I want to use it to mean ,"so much so"?

Example:" la tauromaquia es una tradition arraigada ,tanto que ha cotribuido muchas frases al idioma".
"Tanto los detractores como los defensores..."
Perhaps,the last example is more like,"as many  "..
Anyway,I would like clarification.
I have checked my grammar book and online (kwiziq/spanishdict)but it all deals with comparisons only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Tan" and "tanto" (when invariable) are adverbs:

- La tauromaquia es una tradición arraigada, **tanto** (so deep-rooted) que ha contribuido muchas frases al idioma: Tauromaquia is a deep-rooted tradition, so much so/to such an extent that it has contributed many phrases to the language.
- **Tanto** los detractores como los defensores...: Both critics and supporters... (here "tanto" and "como" form a pair of coordinating conjunctions)

Now, "tanto" (and its variants "tantos", "tanta", "tantas") can also be an adjective and, when the noun is elided, a pronoun:

- Hay muchas tradiciones en nuestra cultura, **tantas** que es difícil enumerarlas. (There are many traditions in our culture, so many that it is difficult to list them all.)
- Hay muchos problemas en nuestro país, **tantos** que no sabemos por dónde empezar. (There are many problems in our country, so many that we don't know where to start.)
- Decían que había mucha corrupción, pero no imaginé que **tanta**. (They said there was a lot of corruption, but I didn't imagine it was so much.)

Comment: Perfect answer,thank you